# Ways to get multiple Kel'Thuzad

Tags: hearthstone

I thought it would be fun to make a deck based around getting multiple Kel'Thuzad(s) (what's the plural of Kel'Thuzad?) onto the board. At my pretty low rank (15) that seems to be an unbeatable situation except vs Priest with Mass Dispel.

**What are all the ways to get multiple KT?** I normally use Faceless Manipulator, but that can't be played on the same turn as KT. I think I've seen cards such as "deathrattle: resummon this minion" and "destroy this minion and return it to life with full health" that I think could work, but I don't have them. I could craft them though since I recently dusted Lorewalker Cho.

Ideally, I'd be able to incorporate them into one of my existing anti-aggro decks since this strategy is kind of moot if mech mage / hunter with way too many snakes kills me by turn 6.

**UPDATE:** In case anyone was interested in how this turned out

[image]

[image]

Comment: I believe the proper form "Kel'Thuzaden".

Comment: @WillihamTotland how do you know that?

Comment: @ChaseC It was a joke. Being, as it is, a proper noun, Kel'Thuzad _has_ no plural. Still, in terms of usual English plural forms, there are three choices: -s, -es, and -en. "Kel'Thuzads" is _clearly_ wrong, and "Kel'Thuzaden" seems to me to roll off the tongue better than "Kel'Thuzades". The most proper rendition is of course "Kel'Thuzad cards".

Comment: @WillihamTotland ......I didn't get that it was a joke. I'm an idiot. I thought it had some deep Warcraft lore associated with it :D

Comment: @ChaseC Deep lore probably contains a better answer

Comment: @ChaseC However, any better answer relies on knowing what, if anything, 'Kel' and 'Thuzad' means individually, and the Warcraft lore languages aren't fully developed, so fat chance.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

All possibilities of getting additional Kel'thuzads in addition to the one that can be put into the deck normally:

1. **Faceless Manipulator**
2. **Sneed's Old Shredder** (1/62 chance of KT)
3. **Recombobulator** on an 8-Drop minion (1/10 chance of KT)
4. **Echo of Medivh**
5. **Unstable Portal** (Incredibly low, but non-zero chance of KT)
6. **Duplicate**
7. **Reincarnate** (New KT resummons old KT at end of turn.)
8. **Ancestral Spirit** (New KT resummons old KT at end of turn.)
9. **Redemption** (New KT resummons old KT at end of turn.)
10. **Resurrect** KT on the same turn he died (New KT resummons old KT at end of turn)

In addition to the above methods controllable by your own deck, mind control effects can steal your opponent's KT if they happen to be running one.

Comment: I think you just mean `1/62 chance of KT` not `1/62 percent chance of KT` as the latter implies 6,200 minions to be selected from.

Comment: @BlackVegetable I always make that mistake ><

Comment: @ChaseC To be fair, question was just posted, and the accepted answer was the first one up, so it makes sense that it hasn't been changed yet.

Comment: @Waterseas Oh, totally understand. I still think having that ability after some amount of karma is a good option :)

Comment: Hey, I was working. Made the change, this is a great answer

Comment: @Dustin Thankees ^^ I personally love exploring such things anyways.

Answer (score 2):

- Faceless Manipulator
- Echo of Medivh
- Reincarnate (resummons a second KT after the end of your turn)
- Ancestral Spirit together with Reincarnate (and optionally Baron Rivendare)

The Shaman spell Reincarnate is probably the most useful of these as it costs only 2 mana and could be played on the same turn.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the quick response! So, are there no paladin, priest, or warlock cards that could accomplish this? It looks like 2 of these cards are for Shaman, who I mostly use for murloc joke deck.

Comment: @Dustin Redemption will bring back KT with 1 health. There are no Priest or Warlock cards that will bring KT back.

Comment: Ohh nice, I would never have thought of that. I generally play Paladin in ranked anyway.

Comment: @Dustin This answer forgot both Redemption, as well as Duplicate.

Comment: @Dustin The answer to your other question - The name of multiple Kel'Thuzads is: Your opponent has left the game if they don't have Deathwing or instant board clear.

Comment: @Dustin Theoretically, Unstable Portal and Sneed's Shredder both have a non-zero percent chance of giving you a second KT as well.

Comment: Theoretically you could trade away your KT on your turn, then use the priest card Resurrect to bring him back, and he should resummon himself at the end of your turn, giving you two KTs.